# RelativeLayout is dynamically created,I am using .scrollBy(), views off screen can't be seen or clicked

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am using scrollBy() on a RelativeLayout to try to scroll over to buttons to the right of the visible screen, but I only see blank screen.
 Buttons on the screen border get clipped, and remain clipped after scrolling (in any direction).

I have tried nearly every combination of WRAP CONTENT and FILL PARENT on the relativelayout params.

I also tried using a LinearLayout in the setContentview(), it didn't work.

I need the view to scroll horizontally, and the app is set to be always in landscape mode.

Does the layout have to be redrawn or refreshed in some manner to enable the missing buttons to appear?

Do I need to use some other view type for this kind of functionality?

Thanks for any input.

-nathan

Here is all the code from top, to end of onCreate():

```
package golfcaddy.tools;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GolfScoreRel extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    // Settings file, preferences

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "golfscore";
    public static final String PREFS_SCORES = "scores";
    public static final String PREFS_BACKGROUND_IMAGE = "backimage";

    SharedPreferences mSettings;

    private int currentX = 0;
    private int currentY = 0;

    int numHoles = 0;
    int numplayers = 0;

      RelativeLayout r1;

      LinearLayout lin;

      public int mLastScoreEntered;

      //manages unique ID's for all view inside Relative layouts
      int viewCount = 1;

     // int holeScoresFront[] = new int[9];
     // int holeScoresFrontb[] = new int[9];
      Button mLastClicked;


      Button exitButton;
      TextView pTotal1;
      TextView pTotal2;


    @Override
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



       // lin = new LinearLayout(this);
       // lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        /*    not used yet....
        GolfPlayer p1 = new GolfPlayer("P 1");
        GolfPlayer p2 = new GolfPlayer("P 2");
        GolfPlayer p3 = new GolfPlayer("P 3");
        GolfPlayer p4 = new GolfPlayer("P 4");
        */

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        r1 = new RelativeLayout(this); // this layout will be set for contentview 

        r1.setLayoutParams(params);



        numplayers = 4;   //standard golf group
        numHoles = 18;  //standard golf round


        r1.addView(createCard(numplayers,numHoles));

        setContentView(r1);


    }  //end oncreate
```

here's my r1.scrollBy() code I borrowed from someplace:

```
Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
          currentX = (int) event.getRawX();
          currentY = (int) event.getRawY();
          break;
      }

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
          int x2 = (int) event.getRawX();
          int y2 = (int) event.getRawY();

          r1.scrollBy(currentX - x2 , currentY - y2);
          currentX = x2;
          currentY = y2;
          break;
      }   
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
          break;
      }
  }
    return true; 
}
```

Screen Shots notes:  We should be seeing 8 more buttons to the right.
              Last shot shows a 5 player card with DEBUG button clipped.

Dang,as a new user, I'm not allowed to post images. try viewing them here:  http://groups.yahoo.com/group/nateandroiddev/photos/album/776905892/pic/list?mode=tn&order=ordinal&start=1&dir=asc

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try since I don't have all the code:

1. Try adding a postInvalidate() to the end of your ACTION_MOVE case.  This will cause the screen to get redrawn.
2. You probably want to add a call to super() in your onTouchEvent method.

If these don't help, a screen shot of your situation would help to clarify what is happening.  It sounds like after scrolling the screen is not being invalidated so you are scrolling an old drawing of the relative layout without causing it to get redrawn.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll try that out. And I'll try to get a screenshot ( I've never taken a screen shot from an actual device, only the emulator)

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get in to see the pictures.  Perhaps imageShack?

Comment: The onTouchEvent method now returns: super.onTouchEvent(event); instead of returning true.  I tried postInvalidate() and invalidate() at the end of the ACTION_MOVE case.  no luck so far.

Comment: Got the screenshots up at imageshack:                        http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/4152/device4png.png
http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/1390/device3.png
http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/8900/device2c.png
http://img262.imageshack.us/img262/1240/deviceh.png